# php form sending array in input's value field with POST

Tags: php, html, forms, multidimensional-array

I have a question about sending data with POST in a form.

I have to send an `array(j, i, 59, j, k, 59);` like value of a checkbox.

Checkbox with same name should accept multiple values, so i need to send a multidimensional array

```
array("sunday", "Monday", ...);
echo "<form action ='' method='POST'>";
// some code...
for ($i = 0; $i < count($day); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $N; $j++) {
        $value = array($va1, $var2, $var3, ..$varN);
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$day" . "[]' value='$value' /> $i-$j";
    }
}
echo "</form>";
```

`var1:varN` are integer that depends by `i, j` and other variables

in `$_POST['Monday']` should be `array((array(par1,..ParN),(array(par1,..ParN))` but it don't work, 
because in the receiving side, code like

```
$Data= $_POST['Monday'] ;
```

gets (using var_dump):

array[k] (Where k is the number of checked box, and it is ok).
Each entry is the string(5)="Array" but i want an array of value, not a string.

Can someone help me? 
Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: You are missing a quote before monday in first line. Also you cant echo an array ($value). Dont echo HTML us ?> to end PHP block and write normal HTML it's alot easyer to read

Comment: @MatejŽvan  I have missing quote during rewriting blocks of code here, source code is ok about sintax. I prefer to echo HTML because my page has 800 line of php and 5 lines of HTML, but next time I'll write normal HTML on stackoverflow if you think it is more understandable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic PHP: An array used in a string context is the literal word `Array`:

```
$foo = array();
echo $foo; // output: "Array"
```

You have this:

```
$value=array($va1,$var2,$var3,..$varN);
^^^^^---- $value is an array

echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$day" . "[]' value='$value' /> 
                                                       ^^^^^^----output in string context
```

If you'd bothered doing a "view source" on your page, you'd have seen the HTML was literally:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='Monday[]' value='Array' />
```

You need to `implode()` that array so it becomes a string:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='{$day}[]' value='" . implode(',', $value) . "' />";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `json_encode($array);` the array into the value field and then just `json_decode($_POST[$day],true);` in case you would want to use more complex arrays.